# White space generated in grid.arrange

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I need to arrange several plots for a figure. I am creating individual plots using base and grid graphics. In order to arrange them in a single figure I have been using `grid.echo()`, `grid.grab(`) to convert to grobs and then `arrangeGrob()` and `grid.arrange()` to build the final figure. A few weeks ago my tentative figure was working fine but now when I rerun the code it produces a figure with whitespace in the margins of the plots.

I add a minimal example that shows the problem that I am facing...

```
##minimal example
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gridGraphics)
##test plot
plot_n1<-plot(1:10,1:10, asp=1)

##convert test plot to grob
grid.echo()
test_p<-grid.grab()

##simulate several plots arranged in a more complex layout
multi<-arrangeGrob(test_p, test_p, test_p, test_p, ncol=1, heights=c(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4))

##create graph
png(filename="minimal_multiplot.png", res=300, width=20, height=20, units="cm")
grid.arrange(test_p, multi, ncol=2, widths=c(2/3,1/3))
dev.off()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please can you edit in the packages you need to run this example (I worked it out but was unable to find a solution). Setting `clip = "on"` in `arrangeGrob` makes it slightly better.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard! Worked perfectly with my code! :))

Comment: `grid.echo()/grid.grab()` are relatively new additions, and from what I can tell still unstable. I don't think there's much that can be done on the gridExtra side, apart from such workarounds.

Comment: among other things, grid.echo() doesn't see to correctly account for the y axis: its title is missing, and the allocated space is wrong. You could report it to the `gridGraphics` maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

There does indeed appear to be a problem when converting a `graphics` plot into a `grid` plot, then using `grid.grab()` to grab and then draw the plot into a smaller regions (i.e., using your method). For instance, using viewports to define a slightly smaller region (coloured grey in the image below), axis material is missing.

```
# Packages
library(grid)
library(gridGraphics)

plot(1:10,1:10)

grid.echo()
test_p = grid.grab()

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(x = 0, width = .85, just = "left"))
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = "grey90"))
grid.draw(test_p)
upViewport()
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "grey90", size = .1, fill = NA))
```

[image]

But Paul Murrell (author of the `gridGraphics` package) offers an alternative (see the examples at `?gridGraphics::grid.echo`, and pp. 156-157 of [*The gridGraphics package* in The R Journal v7/1](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/murrell.pdf)). One can define a function that draws the plot, then that function becomes the argument of `grid.echo()` at the time of  drawing the plot within the viewport. `newpage = FALSE` stops `grid` from opening a new page. Note that none of the axis material is chopped off.

```
pf = function() {
   plot(1:10,1:10)
}

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(x = 0, width = .85, just = "left"))
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col =NA, fill = "grey90"))
grid.echo(pf, newpage=FALSE)
upViewport()
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "grey90", size = .1, fill = NA))
```

[image]

So to get your desired plot, I would do something like this - but still using viewports.

```
pf = function() {
par(mar=c(7.2, 7.2, 1, 1), mex = .3, tcl = .15, mgp = c(3, .15, 0))
plot(1:10, 1:10, cex.axis = .75, cex.lab = .75)
}

grid.newpage()

pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(3, 2, 
      widths = unit(c(2, 1), "null"),
      heights = unit(c(1, 1, 1), "null"))))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 1:3))
grid.echo(pf, newpage = FALSE)
upViewport()

for(i in 1:3) {
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = i))
grid.echo(pf, newpage = FALSE)
upViewport()
}

upViewport()
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "grey90", size = .1, fill = NA))
```

[image]